# Display an Image with OpenCV doesn't work with my Mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, terminal, computer-vision

I am trying a simple Computer Vision program with OpenCV. After creating the Python file, I run it through Jupyter Lab directly on the Terminal to avoid bugs. However, it opens a python3 file (not an image) and I cannot see the image.

I have tried the following:

[Step 1: Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhsn3.png)

[Step 2: File not responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqRvv.jpg)

Do you have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: This seems like you installed QT package with both OpenCV and in Anaconda I'd start by getting rid of one of them.

Comment: I deleted Anaconda through anaconda-clean, don't know if this is what you meant. I still have the same problem.

Comment: conda remove package or conda uninstall package  <- either one of those.  I don't remember the exact package name though.  I think it's pyqt4 at least that what it is for pypi

Comment: thanks for the support. I tried with pyqt4 and pyqt5 but they don't exist on my mac. Therefore, I found pyqt and uninstalled it with conda, but still not working. It is like I have a problem opening the image with the application. I don't have this problem with Windows.

Comment: That's probably the limit of my support because you're getting new errors that I can't see.  Maybe update your question with new info?

Comment: Thanks, Steven. I get no error at the moment. The unique problem is the one illustrated in Step 2 of the question (the file (named python3) is still not responding). This doesn't allow me to see the picture I am pointing to. I have tried the same on Jupyter Notebook, but still nothing. Will continue to dig.